# The sum of the first n odd integers

Tags: r, function, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a function that takes the sum of the first n odd integers, i.e the summation from i=1 to n of (2i-1).

- If n = 1 it should output 1
- If n = 2 it should output 4

I'm having problems using a for loop which only outputs the nth term

```
n <-2
for (i in 1:n)
{ 
  y<-((2*i)-1)                    
}
y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum=0 
n=2
for(i in seq(1,2*n,2)){
   sum=sum+i
}
```

But, of course, R is rather slow when working with loops. That's why one should avoid them.

Comment: Use `cumsum` instead.

Comment: What you say about the `for` loop is not totally true.

Comment: I agree. I just used a for loop to show the user that he can have that structure as well.

Comment: Pascal: maybe I should have said that the option of accessing elements or doing operations inside a `for` loop should be avoidable instead of using R vectorization features.

Answer (score 5):

In R programming we try avoiding for loops

```
cumsum  ( seq(1,2*n, by=2)  )
```

Or just use 'sum' if you don't want the series of partial sums.

Comment: Generating the sequence with `seq_len(n) * 2 - 1` is robust to `n=0` and for me about 2x faster.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually no need to use a loop or to construct the sequence of the first n odd numbers here -- this is an arithmetic series so we know the sum of the first n elements in closed form:

```
sum.first.n.odd <- function(n) n^2
sum.first.n.odd(1)
[1] 1
sum.first.n.odd(2)
[1] 4
sum.first.n.odd(100)
[1] 10000
```

This should be a good deal more efficient than any solution based on `for` or `sum` because it never computes the elements of the sequence.

[[Just seeing the title -- the OP apparently knows the analytic result and wanted something else...]]